# Yii2 after server change can't authenticate via query param auth

Tags: nginx, yii2, authorization

I upgraded my Yii2 application version to the latest - 2.0.46 and changed server from apache to Nginx and now I can't make API GET request from my application using query param auth Given error below

```
<response>
    <name>Unauthorized</name>
    <message>Your request was made with invalid credentials.</message>
    <code>0</code>
    <status>401</status>
    <type>yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException</type>
</response>
```

My API controller looks like this

```
public function behaviors(): array
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::class,
            'authMethods' => [
                QueryParamAuth::class,
            ]
        ];
        $behaviors['language'] = [
            'class' => LanguageSelector::class
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```

I read that similar problem people had with apache servers and editing .htaccess helped, but what about Nginx? Or maybe problem is with new Yii2 version!?

API call example that I am making - examplesite/api/controller/method/?access-token=myaccesstoken&id=myID&lang=lv-LV
As my application is using only get requests, old version and new version uses same DB and on old version API call like example given (with good data) works fine. Can enyone help me?

UPDATE: Nginx config

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
# server_name exsampleserver;
  server_name exampleserverIP
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certdomainexample.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certdomainexample.key;
  ssl_protocols      TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

 access_log /var/log/nginx/app.log upstream_time;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/app-ssl.error.log notice;

 root /srv/www/web/frontend/web;
  index index.php;

 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

 location /api/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?query_string;
  }

 location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;

   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 1200;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 1200;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
  }

 location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

 location ~ /\.git {
    deny all;
  }

  }
```

Comment: Seems like wrong nginx config, can you update your question with nginx config?

Comment: @ustmaestro added update. By the way I am using symlink for API in application frontend folder

Comment: You missed a $ sign. ```try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?query_string;``` must be
```try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$query_string;```

Comment: Don`t forget to restart nginx server after changing config file :)

Comment: @ustmaestro working with symlink $query_string wont work. I posted the answer.

Comment: Added an answer with working nginx config example. This example does not need symlinks

Answer (score 0):

With a help from tech group we founded that working with symlinks in Nginx config $query_params wont work.

So instead of

```
    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?query_string;
  }
```

need to add

```
location /api/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;
 }
```

into Nginx config

Answer (score 0):

Directory structure:

```
examplesite:
    - api
        + models
        + controllers
        + web
    - backend
        + models
        + controllers
        + web
    + common
    + console
    - frontend
        + models
        + controllers
        + web
    + vendor
    + composer.json
```

#### Nginx config for Yii2 advanced app

This config will allow you to use fallowing domain rules:

```
examplesite.test/api   - api folder app
examplesite.test/admin - backend folder app
examplesite.test/      - frontend folder app
```

##### Disclaimer

Use this config only in test environments and if you know how nginx works. For production sites better ask for a specialist help.

```
server {

    #listen *:443 ssl http2;
    listen *:80;    
    server_name examplesite.test;

    #include /etc/nginx/ssl-snippets/ssl-snippet.conf;

    # LOGS - config
    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/examplesite.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/examplesite.error.log;

    # NGINX - config (sizes, charset, caching, ...)
    
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    client_body_buffer_size 32m;

    charset utf-8;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/xml
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    text/javascript
    application/json
    application/x-javascript
    application/javascript;


    # BASE ROOT DIRECTORY for Yii advanced app setup. Default must be the path to your app composer.json. Let suppose it in /var/www/examplesite
    
    set $base_root /var/www/examplesite;
    
    # BASE PHP-FPM SOKET - this is passed to nginx fastcgi_pass, uncoment or add needed version
    
    set $php_server unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #set $php_server unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    #set $php_server unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;

    root $base_root;
    index index.php index.html;

    # FRONTEND APP - location config
    
    location / {
        root $base_root/frontend/web;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /frontend/web/index.php$is_args$args;

        # omit static files logging, and if they don't exist, avoid processing by Yii (uncomment if necessary)
        location ~ ^/.+\.(css|less|js|map|ico|png|jpe?g|gif|webp|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|mov|swf|txt|pdf)$ {
            expires 365d;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        location ~ ^/assets/.+\.php(/|$) {
            deny all;
        }
    }


    # API APP - location config
    
    location /api {
        root $base_root/api/web/;

        # redirect to the URL without a trailing slash (uncomment if necessary)
        #location = /api/ {
        #    return 301 /api;
        #}

        location = /api {
            try_files $uri /api/web/index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # omit static files logging, and if they don't exist, avoid processing by Yii (uncomment if necessary)
        location ~ ^/api/.+\.(css|less|js|map|ico|png|jpe?g|gif|webp|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|mov|swf|txt|pdf)$ {
            rewrite ^/api(/.+)$ $1 break;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        location ~ ^/api/assets/.+\.php(/|$) {
            deny all;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/web/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # BACKEND APP - location config
    
    location /admin {
        root $base_root/backend/web/;

        # redirect to the URL without a trailing slash (uncomment if necessary)
        #location = /admin/ {
        #    return 301 /admin;
        #}

        # prevent the directory redirect to the URL with a trailing slash
        location = /admin {
            try_files $uri /backend/web/index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # omit static files logging, and if they don't exist, avoid processing by Yii (uncomment if necessary)
        location ~ ^/admin/.+\.(css|less|js|map|ico|png|jpe?g|gif|webp|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|mov|swf|txt|pdf)$ {
            rewrite ^/admin(/.+)$ $1 break;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        location ~ ^/admin/assets/.+\.php(/|$) {
            deny all;
        }

        # if your location is "/backend", try use "/backend/backend/web/index.php$is_args$args"
        # bug ticket: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97
        try_files $uri $uri/ /backend/web/index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    
    # PHP FILES HANDLE
    
    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        rewrite (?!^/((frontend|api|backend)/web|api|admin))^ /frontend/web$uri break;
        rewrite (?!^/api/web)^/api(/.+)$ /api/web$1 break;
        rewrite (?!^/backend/web)^/admin(/.+)$ /backend/web$1 break;

        fastcgi_pass $php_server;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
    }
    
    # OTHER LOCATIONS AND RESTRICTIONS
    
    location =  /robots.txt     { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location =  /favicon.ico    { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~* /\.             { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

}
```